# Quantitative Finance books for Practitioners

Tags: options, finance-mathematics, books, financial-markets, application

Currently searching for some books on real options and option pricing. However, the vast majority of the books are quite theoretical, and if someone has been taught these subject in class, half of it is redundant. For instance, most books on option pricing begin with a section about basic terminology of derivatives, another section with elementary statistics, another section with the no arbitrage arguments in discrete time and so on.

**My question is:** *Is there any list of books, focused on practitioners in the broad area of Finance, being relative small and compact? I cannot im*agine myself tracing back in a 1500-pages, chaotic textbook.

Note: Suggestions are not limited in the financial/real option area